# Acrobat Javascript: passing a UTM parameter from URL into a PDF button

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have a PDF that has a button with field name `ctaButton`.

`ctaButton` currently has a url pointing to `https://mywebsite.com`.

I want to host the PDF on my server at `https://mywebsite.com/hosted.pdf`.

And when I send someone a link to the PDF, I want to attach a `UTM_term` parameter `?utm_term=customer1` and then have the PDF read this parameter and update the `ctaButton` url to `https://mywebsite.com/?utm_term=customer1`.

I've been messing around with the Javascript actions in Acrobat for a couple of hours trying to make this happen.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did hours of research and came to this conclusion – Javascript in Acrobat is like trying to code in 1985 AND browsers will not execute whatever code you come up with.

So I used this workaround:

- When I send the PDF to someone, I send it as a link with a `base64`
  encoded stringified JSON package that contains a bunch of tracking
  data but importantly, the name of the file to access as well as utm
  parameters specific to the recipient
- The link hits a server handler (NodeJS) that extracts the encoded
  JSON package, and uses the data in the package to serve up an HTML
  redirect page pointing to the right PDF file
- Importantly, the HTML page also saves the JSON package to the
  browser's `localStorage` . . . this comes in handy in subsequent
  steps
- The PDF file opens in browser (it doesn't have to, could be opened on
  desktop) and the call to action link has a link to a get request
  handler
- The get request handler serves up ANOTHER redirect page
- This second redirect page accesses the browser's local storage, looks
  for the utm parameters I set for that user, and then redirects to the
  sale page, with nice utm parameters attached

So to sum up, you don't add the utm parameters to the call to action link in the PDF (because that would make the world too easy to live in) and instead you do all these acrobatics (no pun intended) to attach utm parameters in the link clicks (via JSON strings saved in `localStorage`) during the process (i.e. when user opens email to extract file via link, and then when user clicks call to action in the PDF).

Any questions or clarifications please let me know in the comments and I will do my best to address.

**Caveats**

- Only works if user uses same browser in all steps (i.e. if Susan opens the email in Safari, saves the PDF, then clicks the call to action in the PDF, and the link opens in Chrome, utm parameters will not be passed).
- Assumes browser is modern and has `localStorage`

---

UPDATE: I came across another solution.  It's a bit more convoluted. Diagram below.

[image]

Porky.io is a Javascript extension for Adobe Indesign.  So flow is:

1. send Porky.io the customer data you need (e.g. utm's for links)
2. Porky.io generates PDF from a template you provide with the customer data you provided
3. Listen for a new file save from Porky
4. Do something with the file (e.g. email it to customer)

I believe you need to run an instance of Windows somewhere in the cloud (e.g. on Azure) to run Indesign with the Porky.io. Unless you want to rely on your laptop.

My project's not big enough yet to warrant setting this up . . . but good alternative if I need to make my current solution more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full url to the document using...

```
var myURL = this.url;
```

"this" in Acrobat JavaScript is the document context.

Comment: thanks - technically correct although I learned browsers won't execute Acrobat code.  See answer I posted for workaround that is working perfectly for me.